# Infinite product and tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Is it well-known that, in general, the natural inclusion map
$$\Pi_{i=0}^\infty k \otimes_k \Pi_{i=0}^\infty k \rightarrow  \Pi_{i,j=0}^\infty k$$ is not an isomorphism. 
However, clearly, this identifies the tensor products as a submodule of $\Pi_{i,j=0}^\infty k.$ How can this submodule be characterized?

Comment: What do you mean by those not being isomorphic? You seem to be considering things only as $k$-modules at the end, but they are clearly isomorphic as such, being of the same dimension.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I meant that the natural inclusion map is not an isomorphism.

Comment: The condition $\det((a_{ij})_{i,j=0}^n)=0$ for $n$ large enough is necessary, but I think it's also sufficient.

Comment: The previous comment is incorrect. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 
$$
V:=\prod_{i,j=0}^\infty k
$$ 
and let $W\subset V$ be the subspace in question.

Let $a:=(a_{ij})_{i,j=0}^\infty$ be in $V.$

Then $a$ is in $W$ if and only if the matrices $(a_{ij})_{i,j=0}^n$ have bounded ranks.

The condition is clearly necessary.

To prove that it is sufficient, assume that $a$ satisfies the condition. Set 
$$
a_{i\bullet}:=(a_{ij})_{j=0}^\infty.
$$ 
For $n$ large enough, each $a_{i\bullet}$ is a linear combination of $a_{0\bullet},\dots,a_{n\bullet}$, say 
$$
a_{i\bullet}=b_{i0}a_{0\bullet}+\dots+b_{in}a_{n\bullet},
$$ 
and we get 
$$
a_{ij}=b_{i0}a_{0j}+\dots+b_{in}a_{nj}
$$ 
for all $i,j$. This implies that $a$ is in $W$, as desired.